# Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'compressor.templatetags.compress': cannot import name 'six'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add .scss to project by this [tutorial](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/how-use-scss-sass-your-django-project-python-way/).
With Django 2 it works fine. But with Django 3.0 I'm getting an error.
I'm creating new project with

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Then doing a part of the tutorial, and getting this error:

```
File "/home/yuriy/Desktop/my/mysite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 125, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'compressor.templatetags.compress': cannot import name 'six'
```

my pip freeze output:

```
    asgiref==3.2.3
Django==3.0
django-appconf==1.0.3
django-compressor==2.3
django-libsass==0.7
libsass==0.19.4
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2019.3
rcssmin==1.0.6
rjsmin==1.1.0
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`django-compressor>=2.4`](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/pull/964) or newer with Django 3.0.

`django.utils.six` was removed in Django 3.0